# Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function and continuous on $(a,b)$. Prove $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, riemann-integration

I'm trying to prove that if $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function, and assuming that $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. Here's my attempt at the proof:

> Since $f$ is continuous, by definition $\exists \delta$ such that $\forall \epsilon > 0$:
>
> $|x - y| < \delta \rightarrow |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$

Now I'm going to guess that I'm supposed to use either the theorem:

> $f$ is Riemann integrable iff $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \text{ partition, } P \text{ s.t } U(f,p) - L(f,p) < \epsilon$

or the theorem:

> $f$ is Riemann integrable with Riemann integral I iff $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \text{ a partition P s.t. } U(f,p)-\epsilon < I < L(f,p) + \epsilon$

to create some sort of epsilon argument. I'm going to try using the first one because if I'm being honest,  I wouldn't know how to go about with the second.

Let $P$ be a partition of $[a,b]$ such that $P=\{a = x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n = b\}$ where the distance between each $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$ is less than $\delta$ (because of continuity?). And then our sup and inf will exist somewhere within our partition:

> $M_i = \sup(f(x))$ where $x\in (x_i, x_{i+1})$
>
> $m_i = \inf(f(x))$ where $x \in (x_i, x_{i+1})$

And here's where I'm stuck. Help or advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hints: use a partition such that the first rectangle (the one containing $a$) is narrow enough so that $(M_0 - m_0) \times \text{width}$ is less than $\epsilon/3$, and similarly for the last rectangle (the one containing $b$). You will need the boundedness in order to do this. Then, use uniform continuity on $[x_1, x_{n-1}]$.

Comment: @Bungo Sorry, but I don't quite understand how to set up the partition. Do we let the partition be something like $P_N = \{a + \frac{0 \cdot (b-a)}{N}, a + \frac{1 (b-a)}{N}.... a+\frac{N(b-a)}{N} = b$?

Comment: You can define it that way (uniformly spaced) but only if you make $N$ sufficiently large. How large does it need to be? Well, if we let $\Delta = (b-a)/N$ for brevity, we would like to simultaneously satisfy $(M_0 - m_0) \Delta < \epsilon / 3$, and $(M_N - m_N) \Delta < \epsilon / 3$, and $\sum_{j=1}^{N-1}(M_j - m_j)\Delta < \epsilon/3$. For the first two conditions, use the boundedness of $f$, and for the last one, use the uniform continuity of $f$ on any closed bounded interval contained in $(a,b)$. Work out how large $N$ has to be to satisfy each condition, then choose the max.

Comment: Do you already know that a bounded continuous function is integrable? The two additonal points cannot do anything to the integral.

Comment: @Alephnull I do know the proof where if f is continuous on closed [a,b], then f is RI on [a,b]. Would the proof then be completely analogous to that?

Comment: @Nikitau It should be. The value at the endpoints is irrelevant. It might contribute to a Riemann sum but not to a limit of Riemann sums.

Comment: @Alephnull Hmm, interesting. Shouldn't the proof somehow try to account for discontinuity at the endpoints and try to show that discontinuity wouldn't impact Riemann integrability? Regardless, I think your point has helped me in understanding what the question is hinting at :).

Comment: @Nikitau Yeah, it is a well-known result (but do you know it?) that the integral over the open interval is the same as the integral over the closed interval. It is even canonized in our notation!